# How to use Swift Flags inside a Run Script Build Phase in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift, run-script

I added "-D MYOWNFLAG" to **Other Swift Flags** in Build Settings of Xcode.
Now, in my Run Script found in Build Phases, I want to check for the existence of the flag "MYOWNFLAG" and execute something (e.g. change Info.plist setting value) if it exists.

Is this possible? If yes, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check all available environment variables by running `printenv` from within a runscript phase.

The *Other Swift Flags* can be printed by running:

```
echo $OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS
```

from within your runscript phase

Comment: how do i get a particular flag? like, i have added DEBUG flag and now i wanna check that in script execution.

Answer (score 10):

Should be able to use wildcards in conjunction with the `$OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS` env variable.

```sh
if [[ $OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS == *"-D MYOWNFLAG"* ]]; then
  echo "execute something (e.g. change Info.plist setting value)"
fi
```